# Select row using object not by index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Table (`DataGridView`) in C# forms application. A List of objects is `binded` to it.
I can get binded object from selected row.

But I also want to select the row programmatically in Table by having only the object from the List. How can I do it?

I don't want to select by `Index` (integer value).

Comment: how is your List looks like?

Comment: @spajce  BindingList<CPatient>

Comment: but why not base on index? you can try the first answer.

Comment: did you use the bindingSource.DataSource = yourBindingList?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't want to worry about getting right index having the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `BindingSource = BindList<CPatient>` you can use this

```
public class CPatient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Load Event*

```
//Global Variable
BindingList<CPatient> bind = new BindingList<CPatient>();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bind.Add(new CPatient { Id = 1, IdNo = "1235", Name = "test" });
    bind.Add(new CPatient { Id = 2, IdNo = "6789", Name = "let" });
    bind.Add(new CPatient { Id = 3, IdNo = "1123", Name = "go" });
    bind.Add(new CPatient { Id = 4, IdNo = "4444", Name = "why" });
    bind.Add(new CPatient { Id = 5, IdNo = "5555", Name = "not" });
    bs.DataSource = bind;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

*Click Event*

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     bs.Position = bs.List.Cast<CPatient>().ToList().FindIndex(c => c.Id == 5);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I suppose you want to set the selected row's index to  bs.Position. But why we are using value 5 there? I need currently selected index, given that I know the object binded to that index.

Comment: the `5` it just a `unique Id` for the person. so we have to use the [.FindIdex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) to select the current index of that person from the `bindingSource`. Try to set the `Id` randomly so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that:

```
var row = dataGrid.Rows
                  .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .FirstOrDefault(r => (CPatient)r.DataBoundItem = myItem);

var rowIndex = row != null ? row.Index : -1;
```

It should return the row index or -1 if grid does not contain a row that was bound using that object.

You can use `row.DisplayIndex` instead of `row.Index` if user is able to reorder the dataGrid in runtime. That because `DataGridViewBand.Index` has following remark:

> The value of this property does not necessarily correspond to the
>   current visual position of the band within the collection. For
>   example, if the user reorders columns in a `DataGridView` at run time
>   (assuming the `AllowUserToOrderColumns` property is set to true), the
>   value of the `Index` property of each column will not change. Instead,
>   the column `DisplayIndex` values change. Sorting rows, however, does
>   change their `Index` values.